# Algorithm for slicing a dynamic graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, uml, slice

I am currently working on a project based on graph and I am searching for an algorithm for slicing an dynamic graph. I have already done some research but most algorithms that I have found works only for a static graph. In my environment, the graph is dynamic, it means that users add/delete elements, create/delete dependences at runtime. 
*(In reality I am working with UML models but UML models can be also represented by typed graphs, wich are composed of typed Vertices and edges)*
I also search for the terms *graph fragmentation* but I did not find anything. And I would like to know if exist such algorithm for slicing a dynamic graph?

**[UPDATE]**

Sorry for not being clear and I am updating my question.Let me first expose the context.

In MDE (Model Driven Engineering), large-scale industrial systems involve nowadays hundreds of developpers working on hundreds of models representing pars of the whole system specification. In a such context, the approach commonly adopted is to use a central repository. The solution I provide for my project (I am currently working on a research lab), is a solution which is peer-to-peer oriented, that means that every developper has his own replication of the system specification.

My main problem is how to replicate this data, the models.
For instance, imagine Alice and Bob working on this [UML diagram](http://bblfish.net/work/atom-owl/2006-06-06/img/AtomOwl-UML.jpg) and Alice has the whole diagram in his repository. Bob wants to have the elements {FeedOrEntry, Entry}, how can I slice this diagram UML? 
I search for the terms of "model Slicing".I have found one [paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.118.7189&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which gives an approach for slicing UML Class Diagrams but the problem with this algorithm is it only works for a static graph. In our context, developpers add/update/remove elements constantly and the shared elements should be consistent with the other replicas.

Since UML Models can also be seen as a graph, I also search for the terms for "graph slicing" or "graph fragment" but I have found nothing useful. 
And I would like to know if exist such algorithm for slicing a dynamic graph

Comment: What do you mean by "slicing"?

Comment: Slicing means takes a sub model or sub graph components based on some criteria. This concept is similar to the program slicing concept

Comment: There might be many algorithms depending on what concrete kind of slicing are you taling about. E.g. algorithms for finding connected components are well known.

Comment: The slicing as explained is heavily depends on the criteria you have chosen. for instance, if your criteria is a clique of size k, this is actually the [clique problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), which is NP-Complete. You should provide more details on the specific slicing criteria.

Comment: @Dimitri, you should definitely update you question to be comprehensible. If we don't know what you are asking then I'm afraid no bounty will help you.

Comment: @Dimitri: It might help, if you give reference to the paper you mention. The problem will be more understandable for us.

Answer (score 1):

If you make slicing atomic, I see no problem with using algorithm shown in paper you linked.

However, for your consistency constraints, I believe that your p2p approach is incompatible. Alternative is merge operation, but I have no idea how would that operation work. It probably, at least partially, would have to be done manually.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply? What make you think that the p2p approach is incompatible?

Comment: Making slicing atomic is not a good choice because our approach is optimist, that means no lock is taken when sharing elements but the synchronization when a conflict is detected.

Comment: It smells a lot like CAP theorem... It's really just a hunch, I should have expressed myself more precisely. Can you guarantee that certain operation has not created a conflict? Optimist approach permits atomicity (if operations are revertible)

Comment: Yes, I can guarantee that certain operation cannot create some conflicts. For instance, when I modify elements not shared by others, there is no possible conflict for this element. But, if  a element is modified simultaneously by two people, so there can be a conflict and the conflict resolution depend on the strategy chosen. For example, last writes wins.

Comment: For this case, I would suggest resolution strategy on conflict- revert. This makes operation behave atomically. If operation is not particularly common (in sense of having a lot of them in the same time) it might work..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like maybe you need a NoSQL graph database such as [Neo4J](http://neo4j.org/) or [FlockDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlockDB).  They can store billions of vertexes and edges.

Comment: Do you think those NoSQL graph database offer the possibility to slice a graph?

Comment: I do not know.  It may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

What about to normalize the graph to an adjacent tree model? Then you can use a DFS or BFS to slice the graph?